# Registering a Named Function as a Listener with Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, click, listener, named

I'm new to javascript/jquery and I've done some poking around the web, but I can't figure out why the following is invalid:

```
var toggleSection = function(sectionName) {
// Do some Jquery work to toggle stuff based on sectionName string
// (concatenate sectionName with other text to form selectors)
};
$('#togglecont1').click(toggleSection("container1"));
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trying to call the function inside the click handler definition, which won't work. you could do something like this:

```
$('#togglecont1').click(function(){
    toggleSection("container1");
});
```